# unable to pause the loop.. how?

Tags: c

```
void distinct (void) {
 char sent;
 int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7;
 FILE *fp2 = fopen ("distinct.txt", "w");

 while (sent != 'n') {
  for (n1=2;n1<=9;n1++) {
   for (n2=2;n2<=9;n2++) {
    if (n2 != n1) {
     for (n3=2;n3<=9;n3++) {
      if (n3 != n2 && n3 != n1) {
       for (n4=2;n4<=9;n4++) {
        if (n4 != n3 && n4 != n2 && n4 != n1) {
         for (n5=2;n5<=9;n5++) {
          if (n5 != n4 && n5 != n3 && n5 != n2 && n5 != n1) {
           for (n6=2;n6<=9;n6++) {
            if (n6 != n5 && n6 != n4 && n6 != n3 && n6 != n2 && n6 != n1) {
             for (n7=2;n7<=9;n7++) {
              if (n7 != n6 && n7 != n5 && /* you get the idea */ && n7 != n1) {
               fprintf (fp2, "%d", n1);
               fprintf (fp2, "%d", n2);
               fprintf (fp2, "%d", n3);
               fprintf (fp2, "%d", n4);
               fprintf (fp2, "%d", n5);
               fprintf (fp2, "%d", n6);
               fprintf (fp2, "%d\n", n7);
              }
             }
            }
           }
          }
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
  printf ("Press any key to continue or 'n' to stop writing the file\n");
  scanf ("%c", &sent);
 }
 fclose (fp2);
}
```

I want the loop to pause whenever the first digit changes to ask whether to continue or stop.

```
2xxxxxx
2xxxxxx
2xxxxxx
Press any key to continue or 'n' to stop writing the file
    // continues if 'y' is entered //
3xxxxxx
3xxxxxx
3xxxxxx
Press any key to continue or 'n' to stop writing the file
    // stops when 'n' is entered //
```

The program I wrote doesn't work as I wish...T___T

Comment: I think my head just exploded. Too much code that looks too much the same. Reduce it.

Comment: Try reading it without indention...

Comment: If I ever write a text editor, I will be sure to make it crash if it detects that many nested levels.

Comment: @jrockway, you may have trouble making any money out of a text editor that crashes with perfectly legal (though not necessarily perfectly readable) C code :-) You may just as well have it crash because the variable names are a bit suspect.

Comment: I'm adding this to the "Most horrific line of code you've ever seen" thread

Comment: @jrockway: Can we add paxdiablo's suggestion ("You may just as well have it crash because the variable names are a bit suspect.") to your editor's feature list, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in terms of readability, you're better putting it at the top of the relevant loop. Get rid of the outer while altogether and change:

```
char sent;
: :
for (n1=2;n1<=9;n1++) {
    for (n2=2;n2<=9;n2++) {
```

into:

```
char sent[100];
: :
for (n1=2;n1<=9;n1++) {
    if (n1 > 2) {
        printf("press any key to continue or 'n' to stop writing the file\n");
        scanf("%s",sent);
        if (*sent == 'n') break;
    }
    for (n2=2;n2<=9;n2++) {
```

The change of `sent` from a character to a string is so you don't need to worry about getting linefeeds as characters (if you type <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you'll get the next *two* sections since <kbd>y</kbd> is one character and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is another - even worse if you enter <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>). The use of a fixed size string and `scanf()` is dangerous however and shouldn't be used in production code. I include it here only yo make your life a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the prompt is inside the *while* loop but outside the outermost *for* loop. Hence the prompt will appear only after all iterations are done. Move the prompt to inside the outermost *for* loop.

Answer (score 2):

If i correctly understand your code you are computing all possible permutations of 8 different numbers. Try using much faster algorhitm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations there are two pseudo code examples. (one for unordered and one for lexicographical orderd permutations)